# How do I add a Type to a graphql-java-annotations project?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

The documentation for graphql-java-annotations doesn't do such a great job of telling me how to add a Custom Scalar to my schema: https://github.com/Enigmatis/graphql-java-annotations/tree/v8.0.1#annotations-schema-creator

What I need is to create some 'scalar Date' in the Schema. It is unclear how to do this with the AnnotationsSchemaCreator builder thing.

```
    GraphQLSchema schema = AnnotationsSchemaCreator.newAnnotationsSchema()
        .query(Query.class) // to create you query object
        .mutation(Mutation.class) // to create your mutation object
        .subscription(Subscription.class) // to create your subscription object
        .directive(UpperDirective.class) // to create a directive
        .additionalType(AdditionalType.class) // to create some additional type and add it to the schema
        .typeFunction(CustomType.class) // to add a typefunction
        .setAlwaysPrettify(true) // to set the global prettifier of field names (removes get/set/is prefixes from names)
        .setRelay(customRelay) // to add a custom relay object
        .build();
```

The docs give me just that. Is a typeFunction what I need here? Do I have to first get the graphql-java "Custom Scalar" stuff set up and put that into the typeFunction?

What's happening right now is that my graphql-java-annotations Types which need the Date type...

```
public abstract class BasePart {
  @GraphQLField
  @GraphQLNonNull
  @JsonIgnore
  public String id;
  ...
  @GraphQLField
  public Date createdOn;
  ...
}
```

Get into the Schema without the Date scalar defined so the GraphiQL UI is rejecting it with errors like...

```
Error: Date fields must be an object with field names as keys or a function which returns such an object.
    at invariant (http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:13:12678)
    at defineFieldMap (http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:14:16395)
    at e.getFields (http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:14:22028)
    at http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:15:22055
    at typeMapReducer (http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:15:22227)
    at http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:15:22200
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:15:22082
    at typeMapReducer (http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:15:22227)
    at typeMapReducer (http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/webjars/graphiql/0.10.1/graphiql.min.js:15:21564)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get that information into the, what, `AnnotationsSchemaCreator.newAnnotationsSchema()` builder?

How do you add a Custom Scalar to a graphql-java-annotations project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeFunction is the key. You pass the TypeFunction when you are building the Schema with the AnnotationsSchemaCreator. The following code effectively got `scalar Date` into the service's GraphQL Schema

```
    graphQLSchema = AnnotationsSchemaCreator.newAnnotationsSchema()
      .query(QuerySchema.class)
      .setAlwaysPrettify(true)
      .typeFunction(new MyDateTypeFunction()) // <-- This got scalar Date onto the schema
      .build();
```

The TypeFunction itself realizes the support for the scalar Date.

```
public class MyDateTypeFunction implements TypeFunction {
  @Override
  public boolean canBuildType(Class<?> clazz, AnnotatedType annotatedType) {
    return clazz == java.util.Date.class;
  }

  @Override
  public GraphQLType buildType(
      boolean b,
      Class<?> clazz,
      AnnotatedType annotatedType,
      ProcessingElementsContainer processingElementsContainer) {
    return MY_DATE;
  }

  public static final GraphQLScalarType MY_DATE = GraphQLScalarType
      .newScalar()
      .name("Date")
      .description("Coerce java.util.Date to/from a String representation of the long value of getTime().")
      .coercing(
        new Coercing() {
          @Override
          public Object serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) throws CoercingSerializeException {
            if (dataFetcherResult instanceof Date) {
              final String result = String.format("%d", ((Date) dataFetcherResult).getTime());
              return result;
            }
            final String message =
                String.format("Expected type java.util.Date but found %s", typeName(dataFetcherResult));
            throw new CoercingSerializeException(message);
          }

          @Override
          public Object parseValue(Object input) throws CoercingParseValueException {
            if (input instanceof String) {
              try {
                return stringToDate((String) input);
              } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                final String message = String.format("NumberFormatException %s", nfe.getMessage());
                throw new CoercingParseValueException(message);
              }
            }
            final String message = String.format("Unable to parseValue %s to a java.util.Date", input);
            throw new CoercingParseValueException(message);
          }

          @Override
          public Object parseLiteral(Object input) throws CoercingParseLiteralException {
            if (input instanceof StringValue) {
              try {
                final String inputStringValue = ((StringValue) input).getValue();
                return stringToDate(inputStringValue);
              } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                final String message = String.format("NumberFormatException %s", nfe.getMessage());
                throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(message);
              }
            }
            final String message = String.format("Unable to parseLiteral %s to a java.util.Date", input);
            throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(message);
          }
        }
      )
      .build();

  public static Date stringToDate(String input) throws NumberFormatException {
    final long inputAsLong = Long.parseLong(input);
    return new Date(inputAsLong);
  }

  public static String typeName(Object input) {
    return input == null ? "null" : input.getClass().getName();
  }

}
```

Note that I'm not recommending that you represent java.util.Date as the String value of the long getTime(), java.time.Instant's ISO-8601 is so much more readable, but my service needed this string value and this is how I got it into a graphql-java-annotation's project schema.